# Parallel Execution of requests in SoapUI

Tags: soap, request, soapui

I have two request that I want to send **simultaneously** to an endpoint to see how it responds. For that reason, I created a test suite that have a test case, in which the two requests are added. From that test, I can run the requests sequentially, which is not what I want.
Can any one help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

- Create two test cases
- Add each request in each test case
- Execute the test suite in `parallel` mode

Comment: How do you run them in parallel as a Load Test? Thanks

Comment: that's the thing ! in 2023 still cannot run a load test with various type fo request; as a real env is. That bear is not so smart.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run TestCases in parallel mode in TestSuite. 
[image: Hope this screenshot help you]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words!  "Execute the test suite in parallel mode" doesn't help much, but your screenshot did.  Many thanks.